# Get UsernamePasswordCredential from HttpServletRequest

Tags: servlets, apache-httpclient-4.x

I'm using Spring SimpleFormController to handle a form submission . when client sets UsernamePasswordCredentials in httpclient by httpclient.getState().setCredentials on Preemptive Authentication, how can i get this UsernamePasswordCredential in server side from HttpServletRequest inside my "onSubmit" method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we can take the 'authorization' header value from the request and Base64-decodes the value to show that the username and password are in fact very easily readable if someone intercepts the network communication. (This is why it's a very good idea to use HTTPS for authentication).

```
     try {
        String auth = request.getHeader("Authorization");
        if(auth!=null&&auth.length()>6){
            String userpassEncoded = auth.substring(6);  
            // Decode it, using any base 64 decoder  
            sun.misc.BASE64Decoder dec = new sun.misc.BASE64Decoder();  
            String userpassDecoded= new String(dec.decodeBuffer(userpassEncoded));
            System.out.println(" userpassDecoded = "+userpassDecoded);
         }
       } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
       }
```